# How can I get replace() function to work properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having an issue with the `replace` function. I have a price like `2,421` and when I use `replace` to remove commas my if test comparing it with `900` still succeeds. Check my code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests 


while True:
    try :
        html = requests.get('https://bitcoinaverage.com/en/bitcoin-price').text
        soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
        price = soup.find("span", {"class": "price"}).get_text().replace(",","")
        print(price)
        if price < '900' : 
            print("correct !")
```

Comment: can you show us the variable value please? also What output do you expect? And why are you treating your errors like that?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Yes - but the date is after both title and author. So you reduce the vspace for an empty date ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing two strings, so `'2421'` is less than `'900'` because `'2'` is less than `'9'`. Convert them both to integers and the comparison will work as you expect:

```
if int(price) < 900 :
```